# Unexpected result in C program, using Malloc and for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, struct, printf, malloc

i have a trouble with my code in C:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int i1,j1,k1;
    int n_block;
    struct  block
    {
        int i,j,k;
    } *blocks;
    n_block=3;
    i1=4;
    k1=3;
    j1=2;
    blocks=malloc(n_block*sizeof(blocks));
    for(int count=0;count<=n_block-1;count++){
        printf("count %d\n",count);
        blocks[count].i=i1;
        blocks[count].j=j1;
        blocks[count].k=k1;
        printf("results:%d\n",blocks[count].i);
        printf("results:%d\n",blocks[count].j);
        printf("results:%d\n",blocks[count].k);
    }
}
```

the expected output is:

```
count 0
results:4
results:2
results:3
count 1
results:4
results:2
results:3
count 2
results:4
results:2
results:3
```

but I obtain:

```
count 0
results:4
results:2
results:3
count 1
results:4
results:2
results:3
count 2
results:4
results:2
results:1970496882
```

I suppose that the last result is the value of the pointer, but why do it happen?

I tried to modify the for loop (without modify the n_block):

```
for(int count=0;count<=n_block+1;count++)
```

and I obtain:

```
count 0
results:4
results:2
results:3
count 1
results:4
results:2
results:3
count 2
results:4
results:2
results:1970496882
count 3
results:4
results:2612
results:10
count 4
results:4
results:2
results:3
```

so, the question is, why does it happen?

Thanks

Comment: `sizeof(blocks)` is the size of a *pointer*. You *sure* that's what you wanted? Doesn't look like it. Try `blocks=malloc(n_block * sizeof *blocks);` ?

Comment: `sizeof(struct block)` and `count < n_block`

Comment: not a problem, but `for(int count=0;count<=n_block-1;count++)` is usually written as `for (int count = 0; count < n_block; count++)`

Comment: [Your code as is](https://ideone.com/IhEjoK) gives some strange output. [A version with the correct `sizeof`](https://ideone.com/jn06Xn) gives the expected output.

Comment: @pmg yes, i think that the problem was on the sizeof(block) as suggested in the answer by u_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `malloc` the statement `sizeof(blocks)` will evaluates to size of a pointer and in your case `sizeof(blocks) != sizeof(struct block)`

change the `malloc` to

```
 blocks = malloc(n_block * (sizeof( struct block) ) ); // more readable
```

`for loop` is over complicated one here, stick to basics

```
for(int count=0; count < n_block; count++ )
```

Comment: Ok, now it works. Why  sizeof(blocks) != sizeof(struct block) ?

Comment: `sizeof *blocks` would maybe be better, in case the type of `blocks` changes.